# What is the proper method of directly calling a specific view in an ASP.NET MVC web application from outside the application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

So, I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly as I'm having an odd issue that I can't figure out. I have an ASP.NET web app for tracking quality issues in a manufacturing environment. Once a new record is created, an email notification gets sent to the appropriate personnel. In that email, I want to include a link that opens up a specific view for that particular record.

In the email, I have the following hyperlink:

```
var link = "<a href = "\"\\webapp-dev\\Nonconformance\\AP\\Details_APInt\\" + nonconform.ID + "\">Click here to view details</a>";
```

The controllers are written in C#. I'm using `SmtpClient` to send an email with that link in the `mail.Body`, along with other info. When I click the URL within the email, I get a `NullReferenceException error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
Line 3:  
Line 4:  @{
Line 5:      ViewBag.Title = "Details_APInt"; <--- failing on this line
Line 6:  }
Line 7:
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] 
    ASP._Page_Views_ap_Details_APInt_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Nonconformance\Views\ap\Details_APInt.cshtml:5
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +251
    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +147
    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +87
    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +106
    System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +374
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +87
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +831
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +395
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +197
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

The strange this is that this working when used with another view, same controller. I basically copied the code for the 'link' variable from the other view's controller action and reused it. The only thing that changes is "Details_APExt" gets changed to "Details_APInt" within the URL.

For the record, I have tried changing

```
var link = "<a href = "\"\\webapp-dev\\Nonconformance\\AP\\Details_APInt\\" + nonconform.ID + "\">Click here to view details</a>";
```

to

```
link = "<a href = \"http://webapp-dev/nonconformance/ap/Details_APInt/" + nonconform.ID + "\">Click here to view</a>";
```

and it produces the same result.

I've made sure that the model is being populated successfully prior to rendering the view. From what I can tell, everything looks good up until it actually renders the view.

I've also tried updating the code to

```
link = "<a href = \"http://webapp-dev/nonconformance/ap/Details_APInt/" + nonconform.ID + "\">Click here to view</a>";
```

for the two views referenced in this question; Details_APExt and Details_APInt (changing the path accordingly for Details_APExt).

These screenshots show how the hyperlink in the email body is rendered. My apologies, I cannot embed photos yet.

This hyperlink works successfully.

[image: This hyperlink works successfully.]

This hyperlink results in the error.

[image: This hyperlink results in the error.]

As you can see, they're essentially identical.

UPDATE:

Details_APInt View:

```
    public ActionResult Details_APInt(int id)
    {            
        var result = GetUserInfo();

        ViewBag.ReplyFrom = result.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString() + " " + result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();

        TempData["FirstName"] = result.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString();

        var nc = db.Nonconforms.Find(id);

        var defect = (from x in db.Defects_Caused
                      where x.Nonconform_ID == nc.Nonconform_ID
                      select x).FirstOrDefault();

        var fromDept = (from f in db.Workcenters
                    where f.ID == nc.From_WC
                    select f).FirstOrDefault();

        var toDept = (from x in db.Workcenters
                      where x.ID == nc.To_Dept
                      select x).FirstOrDefault();

        var type = (from t in db.Nonconform_Types
                    where t.ID == nc.Type
                    select t).FirstOrDefault();

        nc.From = fromDept.Name;
        nc.To = toDept.Name;
        nc.TypeName = type.Name;

        var rolls = (from x in db.Affected_Rolls
                     where x.Nonconform_ID == nc.Nonconform_ID
                     select x).ToList();

        List<Dictionary<string, string>> affectedRolls = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        foreach (var roll in rolls)
        {
            affectedRolls.Add(GetMESInfo(roll.AC));
        }

        ViewBag.affectedRolls = affectedRolls;

        nc.Replies = (from r in db.Replies
                      where r.Nonconform_ID == nc.Nonconform_ID
                      select r).OrderByDescending(x => x.Reply_Date).ToList();

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Defect_Caused = defect;
        vm.Nonconform = nc;

        ViewBag.Time = vm.Nonconform.Date.ToShortTimeString().ToString();
        ViewBag.Phone = result.Properties["telephonenumber"][0].ToString();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Details_APExt View:

```
    public ActionResult Details_APExt(int id)
    {
        var result = GetUserInfo();

        ViewBag.ReplyFrom = result.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString() + " " + result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();

        TempData["FirstName"] = result.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString();

        var nc = db.Nonconforms.Find(id);

        var dept = (from f in db.Workcenters
                    where f.ID == nc.From_Dept
                    select f).FirstOrDefault();

        var type = (from t in db.Nonconform_Types
                    where t.ID == nc.Type
                    select t).FirstOrDefault();

        nc.From = dept.Name;
        nc.TypeName = type.Name;

        var rolls = (from x in db.Affected_Rolls
                     where x.Nonconform_ID == nc.Nonconform_ID
                     select x).ToList();

        List<Dictionary<string, string>> affectedRolls = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        foreach (var roll in rolls)
        {
            affectedRolls.Add(GetMESInfo(roll.AC));
        }

        ViewBag.affectedRolls = affectedRolls;

        nc.Replies = (from r in db.Replies
                      where r.Nonconform_ID == nc.Nonconform_ID
                      select r).OrderByDescending(x => x.Reply_Date).ToList();

        return View(nc);
    }
```

UPDATE:

Just to give a bit more info, the views are expecting the model/ViewModel.

Details_APInt (view):

```
@model Nonconformance.Models.ViewModel
```

Details_APExt (view):

```
@model Nonconformance.Models.Nonconform
```

The only thing I can come up with is the fact that it is using a ViewModel rather than just a model, but I don't understand why that matters if it is being populated successfully prior to rendering the view?

Comment: URLs should always have forward slashes. Even if it’s not a reason for this problem there shouldn’t be any backslashes there.

Comment: Your second example (with forward slashes) is correct. Examine closely the URL being printed in the email versus a known, good url for differences.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Please see the additional info I've provided.

Comment: I haven't read your post, just the title. But I just wanted to point out you don't "navigate to a view" in ASP.NET MVC. A URL will get mapped to an Action Method via a concept called Routing. The action method will then decide what to do with the request, including which view to return.

Comment: The failure on your ViewBag is probably incorrectly identified by VS. Is your view expecting a model from the controller?  Is your controller action receiving the parameter correctly?  What happens if you just navigate directly to the link in your browser?

Comment: @mason - would I then need a separate controller action to handle requests coming from outside the application? I'm just confused as to why one works and the other doesn't and there's virtually no difference between them.

Comment: Can you show us the controller's method (even if just signature)?

Comment: @StevenB. - The Detail_APExt view is expecting a model and the Detail_APInt view gets a ViewModel. The controller action is receiving the parameter correctly and populating the ViewModel successfully. Not every object in the ViewModel contains a value, some are null. Would this make a difference? The controller action only populates the parts of the ViewModel that the view requires, which it does successfully. If I go the view from within the web app (not directly using the url), the view is rendered successfully. There aren't any errors.

Comment: @alans - I've provided the controller actions for both views.

Comment: You should call the action unstead of the view.

Comment: @Pliskin - Can you please be more specific or provide an example? Thank you.